# Cannot access built-in declaration Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Error:(11, 40) Kotlin: Cannot access built-in declaration
    'kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1'. Ensure that you have a
    dependency on the Kotlin standard library

```
fun Route.coroutineHandler(fn: suspend (RoutingContext) -> Unit) {
    handler { ctx ->
        launch(ctx.vertx().dispatcher()) {
            try {
                fn(ctx)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                ctx.fail(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "_In order to use coroutines [...], you need to add a dependency on kotlinx-coroutines-core module as explained [in the project README](https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/README.md#using-in-your-projects)._" – [Coroutines Guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutines-guide.html).

Answer (score 2):

Like [Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw) commented just add the `kotlinx-coroutines-core` dependency to your project as described in the [README](https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/README.md#using-in-your-projects)

#### Maven

Add dependencies (you can also add other modules that you need):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And make sure that you use the latest Kotlin version:

```xml
<properties>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.70</kotlin.version>
</properties>
```

#### Gradle

Add dependencies (you can also add other modules that you need):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5'
}
```

And make sure that you use the latest Kotlin version:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.70'
}
```

Make sure that you have either `jcenter()` or `mavenCentral()` in the list of repositories:

```
repository {
    jcenter()
}
```